# Repeated clicks of JButton automatically

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How to make a `JButton` to be clicked automatically after every second?

I've tried editing the button action performed but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want to trigger a certain action automatically, then *clicking* a button is the wrong approach!

Comment: 1) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) It's probably better that the action listener of the button invoke a method. Then use a Swing `Timer` to invoke that same method. 2) *"I've tried editing the button action performed but that doesn't work."* Why not? What, *specifically* fails? 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use swing's ***Timer*** class and

**doClick**  method with **AbstractButton**.
Here is a full source code.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JButtonTimer extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

    public JButtonTimer() {
        final JButton clickBtn = new JButton("clickMe");
        clickBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());

          }
        });

        add(clickBtn);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clickBtn.doClick();
            }

        });
        timer.start();


    }


    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JButtonTimer());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SwingTimer` and call `doClick` on the button

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ButtonClicker implements ActionListener {

    private JButton btn;
    private Timer timer;

    public ButtonClicker(JButton btn) {
        this.btn = btn;
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btn.doClick();
    }

}
```

See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into WindowOpened Frame event

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, jButton.doClick());
t.start();
```

Comment: Since [`JButton#doClick`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick--) returns `void` your code example won't compile - since `void` is not a instance of `ActionListener`